# Quiero obtener de JSONplaceholder solo los 20 primeros array

Tags: json

*Hola a todos, a ver si alguien me puede ayudar, pongo el código aquí abajo (el HTML y el de Javascript). Lo que quiero es con esta petición a JSONplaceholder obtener solo los primeros 20 datos, ya que son 5000 en total. Además como pueden ver de estos primeros 20 solo obtengo los items llamados id, title, url. Entiendo que tengo que aplicar un bucle for en vez de un forEach pero no se como hacerlo. Y además quisiera saber si es posible y como obtener siempre en esta misma petición que cada item este en una celda, y NO los tres en una sola.
O sea "id" dentro de su celda, y al lado "title" en su celda y a lado "url" en su celda. Y de bajo el resto de items cada uno en su celda, de manera de obtener una estructura con 3 celdas en linea, y así hasta la linea 20, una abajo de la otra.
Espero de explicarme bien.. Gracias!*
el HTML:

```
    `<body>
     <table id="miTabla" border="1" cellspacing="2" cellpadding="5">
      <thead>
       <tr>
        <th>Id - Título - URL</th>
       </tr>
      </thead>

     </table>
     <script src="mod4Practica3.js"></script>
     </body>`
```

Javascript:

```
    `(() => {
     const miTabla = new XMLHttpRequest(),
     $miTabla = document.getElementById("miTabla"),
     $fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

     miTabla.addEventListener("readystatechange", (e) => {
     if (miTabla.readyState !== 4) return;


     if (miTabla.status >= 200 && miTabla.status < 300) {
      let json = JSON.parse(miTabla.responseText);

     json.forEach((el) => {
     const $tr = document.createElement("tr");
     const $td = document.createElement("td");
     $td.innerHTML = `${el.id} -- ${el.title} -- ${el.url}`;
     $fragment.appendChild($tr);
     $fragment.appendChild($td);
     });
      $miTabla.appendChild($fragment);
     } else {
      let message = miTabla.statusText || "Ocurrió un error";
      $miTabla.innerHTML = `Error ${miTabla.status}: ${message}`;
     }
     });

     miTabla.open("GET", "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/photos");

     miTabla.send();
     })();`
```